# siunitx in scrreprt - problems with beamer class

Tags: beamer, miktex, siunitx

I want to use the usepackage `siunitx` for my thesis (`scrreprt`). MikTeX asks for installing the documentclass `beamer` each time when I compile my document (and then freezes while installing). When I cancel the installation of the beamer package, the document is compiled correctly and displays the correct number with SI unit.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{5}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

How can I avoid the installation message? It does not affect anything, it is just annoying.

Thank you!

```
*File List*  
scrreprt.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (report)  
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)  
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)  
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)  
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)  
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)  
scrsize11pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)  
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)  
 siunitx.sty    2013/03/11 v2.5q A comprehensive (SI) units package  
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper  
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives  
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code  
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)  
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)  
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)  
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)  
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)  
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)  
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)  
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)  
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions  
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion  
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists  
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks  
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers  
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks  
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures  
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists  
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation  
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists  
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages  
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations  
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips  
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces  
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points  
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes  
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer  
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support  
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions  
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel  
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser  
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01  
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0  
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)  
l3keys2e.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys  
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)  
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)  
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive  
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX  
supp-pdf.mkii  
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2013/03/11 v2.5q siunitx: Abbreviated units  
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions  
 ***********
```

Comment: Run your editor as an administrator.

Comment: I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter, and unfortunatelly it does not work even if I run it as administrator

Comment: What happens if you force miktex to install beamer separately (by trying to compile a beamer document)?

Comment: It freezes...I tried this also using the package manager, but there is some problem with beamer. And I do not know why I should need beamer for the siunitx package, they do not seem to be related in any way.

Comment: This means that MiKTeX is looking for a file that has the same name as a file in the beamer package.

Comment: Just a short explanation why siunitx wanted to install beamer: at the time this questions was posted, the `translator` package was part of beamer and if you want to use all possible features of siunitx, the translator package needs to be installed. In the mean time, the translator package became an independent package, so it should no longer be necessary to install beamer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a problem with your installation of MiKTeX, if it is the current one. I guess you have installed basic MikTeX? See the first line of your log file. Do you see `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)`?

If **no**, you should update.

If **yes**, your installations is faulty.

Try to reboot your computer. Do you still have the error? If **Yes** follow this:

1. Delete the old installation completly! including TeXnicCenter.
2. Download the installer for complete MiKTeX from http://www.miktex.org
3. Install complete MiKTeX
4. Download TeXnicCenter from http://www.texniccenter.org
5. Install TeXnicCenter. It should recognize that you have an installed MiKTeX.
6. Now compile your MWE 3 times. It should run. If not, you have a problem with your computer.

**Edit**: I compared your file list with mine.  You are using old packages for `siunits` and `expl3.sty`. My File List says:

```
 siunitx.sty    2013/07/31 v2.5s A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
```

and you have version 2.5q (older) and v4469 (older).  Please use the MiKTeX package manager to update your packages.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I did a complete new installation of MikTeX and TeXniccenter. Unfortunately the error is still there.

Comment: I added the file list. Yes, it still wants to install `beamer`.